# Jq convert an object into an array

Tags: json, jq

I have the following file "Pokemon.json", it's a stripped down list of Pokémon, listing their Pokédex ID, name and an array of Object Types.

```
[{
  "name": "onix",
  "id": 95,
  "types": [{
      "slot": 2,
      "type": {
        "name": "ground"
      }
    },
    {
      "slot": 1,
      "type": {
        "name": "rock"
      }
    }
  ]
}, {
  "name": "drowzee",
  "id": 96,
  "types": [{
    "slot": 1,
    "type": {
      "name": "psychic"
    }
  }]
}]
```

The output I'm trying to achieve is, extracting the name value of the type object and inserting it into an array.
I can easily get an array of all the types with

```
jq -r '.pokemon[].types[].type.name' pokemon.json
```

But I'm missing the key part to transform the name field into it's own array

```
[ {
  "name": "onix",
  "id": 95,
  "types": [ "rock", "ground" ]
}, {
  "name": "drowzee",
  "id": 96,
  "types": [ "psychic" ]
} ]
```

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [man](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) it states you have an option to use [map](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) - which essentially means walking over each result and returning something (in our case, same data, constructed differently.)

This means that for each row you are creating new object, and put some values inside

Pay attention, you do need another iterator within, since we want one object per row.
(we simply need to map the values in different way it is constructed right now.)

So the solution might look like so:

```
 jq -r '.pokemon[]|{name:.name, id:.id, types:.types|map(.type.name)}' pokemon.json
```

Comment: I think you need to wrap the the entire expression in square brackets to return a JSON array. e.g. `'[.pokemon[]|{name:.name, id:.id, types:.types|map(.type.name)}]'`. Refer to the following example(s): [_Transforming input_](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/jq-is-sed-for-json#transforming-input) and [_How to transform JSON_](https://shapeshed.com/jq-json/#how-to-transform-json)

Comment: The object construction can be simplified e.g. to: `{name, id, types: [.types[].type.name]})`